# Dealing with ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code

Tags: python, google-cloud-spanner

I have this code:

```
from google.cloud import spanner



def search_topic2(request):
    return 2
```

I am compiling it with
gcloud.cmd functions deploy search_topic2 --trigger-http  --runtime python39

Very simple example
and I get
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.
I know it is caused by "from google.cloud import spanner"....
Any idea what is the problem exactly and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put all dependencies/packages you want to use in you code in file named `requirements.txt`. If your required package is available there it will be ready to import. As on setup of environment cloud function installs all packages mentioned in `requirements.txt` at backend. Following is a sample `requirements.txt`

```
google-api-core==2.0.1
google-auth==2.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib
google-cloud-bigquery==2.26.0
google-cloud-core>=2.0.0
google-crc32c
```

**Version information is optional**

You can write it manually or obtain it by using `pip freeze>requirements.txt` (in case you are shifting from local environment to cloud function)